# Is there has any support for custom queries in spring-data-gremlin?

Tags: java, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB. I wanted to write custom queries using **spring-data-gremlin** API.

Is there any option for writing custom queries?

**Example:**

```
@Query(name="Program.findByMajorCategoryName",query="g.V().has(label, 'Program').has('majorCategory',containing(?))")
```